# Getting my box collision function to recognise arguments passed to prototype constructor

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a noob learning to work in JavaScript & HTML5 Canvas and I'm working on my first 2D game.

Thank you in advance for any tips you can provide me with.

For some reason after I change the enemy constructor function to accept object dimensions as parameters, the dimensions of Enemy are not passed to the collision detection function. This results in my Player object not being affected when crossing paths with the Enemy object.

Here is my Enemy constructor function:

```
// Create subclass Enemy
function Enemy(x, y, speed, leftSide, rightSide, top, bottom) {
    Sprite.call(this, x, y);
    this.speed = speed;
    // Set variables for enemy dimensions
    this.leftSide = leftSide + this.x;
    this.rightSide = rightSide + this.x;
    this.top = top + this.y;
    this.bottom = bottom + this.y;
    this.sprite = 'images/enemy-bug.png';
}
```

Here are the arguments I pass through it:

```
var allEnemies = [
    new Enemy(0, 225, 60, 0, 70, 0, 75)
    ];
```

Here's my collision detection function:

```
function checkCollisions () {
    allEnemies.forEach(function(enemy) {
             if(enemy.leftSide < player.rightSide &&
                enemy.rightSide > player.leftSide &&
                enemy.top < player.bottom &&
                enemy.bottom > player.top) {
                    console.log('collision!');
                  //Reset player position
                    player.startOver();
                }
            });
}
```

How can I get my collision detection function to recognise the dimension values? My player is walking around with impunity =(

Again, many thanks for any assistance you can provide and I do apologise if my post doesn't conform to question standards. This is my first post on StackOverflow.

Comment: If you comment back quickly we can go on jsfiddle and I'll help you out one on one

Comment: Hi, I'm here if you still want to help me out. Thanks =)

Comment: yea you were a bit late. idk when you going to see this and when I'm getting back on stackoverflow. but open a jsfiddle, paste your code, click collaborate and paste the link here

Comment: Oh cool. Thx. I'll do that, but first, should I paste ALL of my code or just what I have mentioned above? Cheers!

Comment: I notice that in the `Enemy` constructor is using properties such `leftSide + this.x` or `top + this.y`. I suppose that **`Sprite.call(this, x, y)`** is setting that properties in the object, i.e. **`function Sprite(x, y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }`**. If it is not, then you should rewrite your `Sprite` function.

Comment: @Edwin I tried pasting all of my code in jsfiddle, but I don't get a result. My .js code is spread over three different text files. I tried combining them into one, but when I do the code doesn't run. Should I just paste it all anyway?

Comment: @jherax Yes, that is correct. `Sprite.call(this, x, y)` is setting the properties in the object as you mentioned, so I don't think that is the problem: `function Sprite(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}`

Comment: @Edwin - jsfiddle.net/RebelExplorer/br5bkse4/3 I ended up changing it... was gonna post the change here, but I can't format it, so it'd be quite messy. You can see my update in the link. It works now, but I'm sure there's a better a way! My new problem is calling main() on page app.js from an anonymous function defined in the variable Engine from the page engine.js . Here's my github address for the project in case that's easier to look at: https://github.com/RebelExplorer/frontend-nanodegree-arcade-game

game link:

http://rebelexplorer.github.io/frontend-nanodegree-arcade-game/

Comment: What's a good time for you to get on because right now were relying on just whenever we answer back? Well assuming from your github if you live in vietnam, you're 11 hours ahead of me

Comment: Oh. I didn't realise you had wanted to communicate in real time. How's 8PM tonight your time (Saturday)?

Comment: Yo I'm so sorry, I had just clicked on your question in my notifications. Just to see if I missed anything and looks like I did. Stackoverflow for some reason did not show your comment on my notifications

Comment: Hey man, no worries! I've been busy the last few days anyway. As far as my problems are concerned, I think I've handled them for the most part, but I really appreciate your efforts to help me out.

Comment: alright Idk why I'm not getting your notifications. I'm not sure if you're suppose to tag me or something like this: @RebelExplorer. I believe the reason I don't have to tag you is because it's your question. Also I saw what you build pretty cool. But if you like I'd like to help you refactor your code. I saw it, and I think it could be a little bit better and shorter.

Comment: @Edwin Did you get notified that time? Thanks bro =) I'm new at this, so it's def gonna take some time until I can streamline a lot of this. That being said, this is actually an assignment, so I can't receive any overt outside help now; however, once I've received feedback etc. I can do whatever I want with it, which I plan to do. If you're still game then, I'd love any help you could provide.Cheers!

Comment: @Edwin Will do! Got your email now, so feel free to delete =)

Comment: alright email me whenever